# Abbreviation of "In contrast"

Tags: abbreviations

What word can I use as an abbreviation of the phrase "in contrast" or "on the contrary" or "directly opposite"?

Comment: Good question.  I don't think there is one, at least not in common use.  Is there a reason you feel it's necessary, or is it just idle curiosity?

Comment: Can you show how you want to use "in contrast", could you give an example sentence.

Comment: Literally an abbreviation? Is an abbreviation a word?

Answer (score 2):

A contrast is a comparison, the sharp one. I don't know an abbreviation for "in contrast to" but "compare (imperative)" is usually abbreviated to **cf.** [Latin *confer* (compare)].

Answer (score -1):

I have used "cfx" for "contrast". "Compare" is abbrev. cf. and since "contrast" is a comparison, I used that abbrev., plus the x as a graphic of opposing ideas.